# Extension method to return datatypes based on object type

Tags: c#, extension-methods

Hi all I am planning to write an extenstion method which needs to handle every data type with in the same method and return the appropriate one. This is what I tried

```
public static dynamic extension(this object o)
    {
        var v = o.GetType();
        switch (Type.GetTypeCode(o.GetType()))
        {
            case TypeCode.Int32:
                return intTryparse(o);
        }
    }

 private static int intTryparse(object o)
    {
        int retunrInt = 0;
        int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(o), out retunrInt);
        return retunrInt;
    }
```

But I couldn't get the required so can some one help me? One extension method which should give result for datatypes such as `int,string,decimal,double,boolean`

This methods I would like to convert to one method by passing an object

http://www.dailycoding.com/Posts/top_5_small_but_must_have_extension_methods.aspx

If you see the extension methods there for long to return `Int16,Int32..` I would like to combine all together in one method and return similary that code should work for remaining datatypes as mentioned

Comment: You can use generics though it would be a generics abuse.

Comment: Your question is unclear and your code is deeply flawed, so you probably won't get any useful comments or answers.  I mean that entirely in a constructive way.  Read [this article](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to learn how to improve your question.  (Edit: Improved hyperlink.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I guess you don't need it. Try to redesign your solution.

Second, given examples are about converting of **string** to **something**, **NOT** **something** to **something**.

I think, this will work for your needs:

```
public static class StringExtension
{

    public static T ConvertTo<T>(this string o)
    {

        if (typeof (T) == typeof (Int32))
            return (T) (object) Int32.Parse(o);
        if (typeof (T) == typeof (Int16))
            return (T) (object) Int16.Parse(o);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Double))
            return (T) (object)Double.Parse(o);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Boolean))
            return (T) (object)Boolean.Parse(o);
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Decimal))
            return (T) (object)Decimal.Parse(o);

        throw new ApplicationException("Cannot convert to type " + typeof(T));
    }

}
```

use:

```
var shortResult = "12".ConvertTo<Int16>();
```

another approach suggests to use pure reflection, thus it can be a bit more pretty, but also more slow.

**Again, I absolutely don't recommend you to use this!**

UPD:

```
if (typeof (T) == typeof (Int32))
{
   Int32 result = 0;
   Int32.TryParse(o, out result);
   return (T) (object) result;                
}
```

Comment: Hi what if I pass a null object here?

Comment: Updated according to implementation logic in your question

Comment: This code solves your problem, but again I want to emphasize that probably it's better to redesign your solution. This code looks a bit ugly and also it performs slowly than solution based on some (5) separate methods.